# Error Creating Blob for "x.jpg" Status 500

Tags: ruby-on-rails, blob

Users can create posts and upload images attached to these posts on our website. At the moment, we're receiving blob creation errors. Because it's a 500 error, I'm not having this issue in local development and so I can't test solutions. I've seen a few mentions of active_storage on google but am not sure how to approach that for this specific problem. Any help is greatly appreciated!

[Current error displaying on the live site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/379F7.png)

Comment: Can you provide more information? I recently had a similar issue as what you are describing and it was because I had improperly written my production config for active_storage (config file located at config/storage.yml).

Comment: @obiruby What more information do you need? I'm not too sure what else to add; we've only been having this issue recently, not sure what changed. To my knowledge the storage.yml hasn't been touched.

Comment: what would be great to see is the output from the production log file - hopefully it will show a backtrace with more information that we can use to track down the cause of the error. Also good to see would be the code from the controller file that triggers the error and the snippet from the model file that implements active_storage

Comment: Did you sort this out?

Comment: The issue was resolved @JoeBloggos, but I wasn't the one who ended up fixing it. I just went through our githubs PR history and can't quite find it sorry!